# Remove custom post type slug not working for child pages

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, child-pages

I'd like my custom post type, products, to not use a slug, eg: domain.com/product-name. The code below sorts that out nicely, however it fails to work with child pages, eg: domain.com/product-name/product-name-feature, it 404s.

I originally tried giving the custom post type the rewrite slug as '/', and while this was great for the custom post type, it killed normal pages (404). So if the solution is to use '/' and then fix normal pages, that's fine too.

```
// Post Type

function base_types() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Products & Features',
        'singular_name'      => 'Product',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Product / Feature',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Product',
        'new_item'           => 'New Product',
        'all_items'          => 'All',
        'view_item'          => 'View Product / Feature',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Product / Feature',
        'not_found'          => 'None found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'None found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Products / Features'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'product', 'with_front' => false ),
        'capability_type'    => 'page',
        'has_archive'        => false,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'menu_position'      => 10,
        'with_front'         => false,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-chart-bar',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'page-attributes' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'product', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'base_types' );


// Rewrites

function remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'product' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    if( $post->post_parent ) {

        $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/' . $parent->post_name . '/', '/' . $parent->post_name . '/', $post_link );

    }

    else {

        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_slug', 10, 3 );


function parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'product', 'page' ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'parse_request' );
```

First level pages work as expected. The child pages get the correct permalink, but they 404.

Can anyone help or point in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using the Permalink Setting: Custom Structure of /%post_id%/

Didn't find this answer anywhere else, so added it in myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will replace the slug `product` without 404 error for both parent and child pages.

```
/**
 * Strip the slug out of a hierarchical custom post type
 */

if ( !class_exists( 'product_Rewrites' ) ) :

class product_Rewrites {

private static $instance;

public $rules;

private function __construct() {
    /* Don't do anything, needs to be initialized via instance() method */
}

public static function instance() {
    if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
        self::$instance = new product_Rewrites;
        self::$instance->setup();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function setup() {
    add_action( 'init',                array( $this, 'add_rewrites' ),            20 );
    add_filter( 'request',             array( $this, 'check_rewrite_conflicts' )     );
    add_filter( 'product_rewrite_rules', array( $this, 'strip_product_rules' )           );
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', array( $this, 'inject_product_rules' )          );
}

public function add_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_tag( "%product%", '(.+?)', "product=" );
    add_permastruct( 'product', "%product%", array(
        'ep_mask' => EP_PERMALINK
    ) );
}

public function check_rewrite_conflicts( $qv ) {
    if ( isset( $qv['product'] ) ) {
        if ( get_page_by_path( $qv['product'] ) ) {
            $qv = array( 'pagename' => $qv['product'] );
        }
    }
    return $qv;
}

public function strip_product_rules( $rules ) {
    $this->rules = $rules;
    # We no longer need the attachment rules, so strip them out
    foreach ( $this->rules as $regex => $value ) {
        if ( strpos( $value, 'attachment' ) )
            unset( $this->rules[ $regex ] );
    }
    return array();
}

public function inject_product_rules( $rules ) {
    # This is the first 'page' rule
    $offset = array_search( '(.?.+?)/trackback/?$', array_keys( $rules ) );
    $page_rules = array_slice( $rules, $offset, null, true );
    $other_rules = array_slice( $rules, 0, $offset, true );
    return array_merge( $other_rules, $this->rules, $page_rules );
}
}

product_Rewrites::instance();

endif;
```